# Room TypeConverter for compose Color class

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create TypeConverter for `Color(androidx.compose.ui.graphics)` class but room fails at coompile time with error

```kotlin
error: Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods.
public final class ColorConverter {
            ^
```

Color class (in compose)

```kotlin
value class Color(val value: ULong) {
...
}
```

ColorConverter implementation

```kotlin
object ColorConverter {
    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun toLong(color: Color): Long = color.value.toLong()

    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun toColor(value: Long): Color = Color(value)
}
```

I've declared in DB as well

```kotlin
@TypeConverters(ColorConverter::class)
```

Comment: As sad as it is, TypeConverter does not recognize inline class (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124624218). If you look at the Color class, it has 'value' modifier which make it an inline class. For now, you might have to store the color as Int or Long.

Answer (score 1):

Because Room compiler doesn't support inline classes (value classes). But good news is new alpha version 2.6.0-alpha01 now support it.

[https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#:~:text=Supporting%20value%20classes%20in%20Room%20for%20KSP.%20Room%20is%20now%20able%20to%20support%20value%20classes%20in%20Entities.%20(4194095)](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#:%7E:text=Supporting%20value%20classes%20in%20Room%20for%20KSP.%20Room%20is%20now%20able%20to%20support%20value%20classes%20in%20Entities.%20(4194095))

Answer (score 0):

```
class ColorConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toLong(color: Color): Long = color.value.toLong()

    @TypeConverter
    fun toColor(value: Long): Color = Color(value)
}
```

Instead of making **ColorConverter** as object, make it as a normal class and remove **@Jvmstatic** annotation from method.
I think it will solve the issue.

Comment: Nope, I tried that as well first. But didn't worked.